# sum distinct values from a column in datagridview

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, sum

I have a datagridview with two columns like this:

```
 group | quantity
------------------------
   chest  |  3
   legs   |  7
   back   |  2
   chest  |  1
   back   |  5
   legs   |  2
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the sum of distinct group to a list and use that list for populate another datagridview.

So the result must be in this example:

```
   chest  |  4
   legs   |  9
   back   |  7
```

I've tried some linq query code but without any success.

How can I do it?

Here's some Linq queries I tried:

```
List<string> vv = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(x => !x.IsNewRow)
    // either..
    .Where(x => x.Cells[7].Value != null)
    //..or or both
    .Select(x => x.Cells[7].Value.ToString())
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

dataGridView6.DataSource = vv;
```

EDIT

the group column is being auto filled after a selection of another column combobox, the quantity is filled manually. For the group by I found this code and works but throw an error if a cell is empty:

```
    var Sums = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                  .GroupBy(row => row.Cells[7].Value.ToString()) // group column
                  .Select(g => new { User = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value)) });
dataGridView6.DataSource = Sums.ToList();
```

Comment: Can you show the Linq query you already tried please?

Comment: @Martin I've tried different codes. Now I have this but it doesnt do the sum and it doesnt get the group name. For some reason it return the lenght of the  group name: List<string> vv = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                           .Where(x => !x.IsNewRow)                   // either..
                           .Where(x => x.Cells[7].Value != null) //..or or both
                           .Select(x => x.Cells[7].Value.ToString())
                           .Distinct()
      
                           .ToList();
            dataGridView6.DataSource = vv;

Comment: It will be easier to perform this operation on the data collection which is used as datasource to the GridView.

Comment: It's not possible since the datagridview is manually populated

Comment: you need to use group by linq method for this

Comment: You would be better off using data binding and have the original data in a list. You then apply the linq query on the list instead of the DataGridView. Much cleaner and much more maintainable.

Comment: Can you see my last edit?

Comment: Did you get the desired result with the latest code you shared?

Comment: ok, I'm almost there with the code of last edit. I put the code on a button click and works, but I get an error here if I have an empty row: .GroupBy(row => row.Cells[7].Value.ToString()). Do you know How I can handle the null value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, here the solution that works:

```
var Sums = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
          .Where(row => row.Cells[7].Value != null)
        .GroupBy(row => row.Cells[7].Value.ToString()) // group column
        .Select(g => new { User = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value)) }); // quantity column

        dataGridView6.DataSource = Sums.ToList();
```